# PostbackUrl vs NavigateUrl

Tags: asp.net, navigateurl, postbackurl

Can someone tell me the different between LinkButton.PostBackUrl and HyperLink.NavigateUrl?  I've got a asp.net 2.0 application that uses both methods throughout the application and everything works fine.  However if I connect to the application over the company vpn all of the links that use LinkButton.PostBackUrl give me a (54) Connection reset by peer error and the HyperLink.NavigateUrl work just fine.  I want to know the underlying difference between the commands so I can try to figure out what the vpn software is blocking that is causing the Connection reset by peer error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NavigateURL: Submits a 'Get' request to the URL (just like if you had typed it in your browser)

PostBackURL: Submits a 'Post' request containing the information from the form to the specified URL; I don't believe this is commonly used

Answer (score 3):

The PostBackURL for the linkbutton tells you which form the button is posting data to. (more [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.postbackurl.aspx))

The NavigateURL for the Hyperlink tells you which control, the link is getting from the server.

Comment: Sorry to open up convo on an old subject....Do these basically act the same on a webpage? I recently changed a HyperLink to a LinkButton and don't want to mess anything up on the page.

Comment: The behaviors are similar, and can be replicated between each other, but they do not do the SAME thing on a webpage.  A linkbutton, by default, POSTS the page to itself (i.e. the IsPostBack flag is TRUE) in the same fashion as a standard button.  A Hyperlink sends a GET request to whatever URL is provided in the NAVIGATEURL property.

Answer (score 2):

PostBackUrl first posts or sends the current web form to server and then redirects you to the specified url,while NavigateUrl directly takes you to the url specified without submitting the current page to the server